# Why are Skyscraper(a Qayamat Sign) encouraged in Gulf?

Tags: islamic-events

This has baffled me a lot. Everyone is aware that one of the many Qayamat(Judgement Day) signs is that there will be tall/strong skyscraper's in the world.

I would like to know, when there is a majority of population in Gulf follower of Islam, why does this region encourage and implement (example - the tallest skyscraper is in Dubai) the above Qayamat Sign vividly?

At least, there should be some resistance to this in the Gulf and the people there should not be the one who become part of making a Qayamat Sign come true.

Comment: Questions about "why do X Muslims do Y" are generally off topic for this site. I suggest you reconstruct your question to ask about the meaning and interpretation of this sign -- that would be more on-target for this site.

Comment: While this question, as phrased, is off-topic, the single posted answer is quite good.  The whole thread can be redeemed with some work (for example, reworking the core question to something more like "Does building skyscrapers (as is encouraged in the Gulf) hasten the end of the world?")

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What must be realized is that the Alamat Al-Qiyama are *signs*, not *causes*. The Qiyama will not happen *because* someone is building tall buildings, it will happen because Allah *wills* it. The time of Qiyama has already been set, and the signs just mean that this time is coming closer and closer (as it naturally should given the nature of time).

Taking this sign in particular, here's an excerpt from a longer hadith that mentions it:

> He said, "Inform me about the Hour." He (the Messenger of Allah) said,
>   "About that the one questioned knows no more than the questioner." So
>   he said, "Well, inform me about the signs thereof (i.e. of its
>   coming)." Said he, "They are that the slave-girl will give birth to
>   her mistress, that you will see the barefooted ones, the naked, the
>   destitute, the herdsmen of the sheep (competing with each other) in
>   raising lofty buildings."

Many people have interpreted *"the barefooted ones, the naked, the destitute, the herdsmen of the sheep"* to be the Bedouin tribes of Arabia, but I'm not going to get into how accurate that interpretation is. What *is* apparent is the sense of unlikeliness of this event happening during the time of the Prophet. In other words, enough time has advanced from the event of narration that the unlikely has become the norm. Thus Qiyama is getting closer and closer.

Remember the golden mantra of statistics: "correlation is not causation".